# Do we really need the tag "diy" on the site?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blacklist

I've just spotted a question that had the single tag [diy](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy).

Now, aside from the fact that the question really should have had different tags, do we really need such a tag given that the site is all about DIY?

If we're in agreement we can get the tag blacklisted so no one can use it. We'll have to retag any existing questions first.

Are there any other tags that should be blacklisted?

There was a [similar question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/824/blacklist-electronics-tag) on the electronics site about the `[electronics]` tag.

Comment: The [diy] tag resurfaced (until I removed it) today on this question: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11838/what-would-be-a-good-material-for-a-portable-video-projection-surface.

Answer (score 6):

I agree, DIY is a redundant tag and should be closed - if only we had some "trusted users" who could close vote it. ;)

Comment: Well there are only the three closed questions now. If there are no arguments I can delete those and then make the request for the blacklist.

Comment: I mean the tag itself.  20k rep users can actually vote to delete tags.

Comment: Ah - no, there no options to delete tags at all. If no questions are have the tag it's purged from the system after 24(?) hours. This means that new users can't use it but a high rep user could add it back in again. Hence the need to blacklist it, but that's a developer only ability.

Comment: Ah, I misread this - I thought it allowed tag deletion.  http://diy.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user

Comment: Just editing tag wikis and deletion of question/answers

Comment: @ChrisF Normally tag blacklisting is only needed if you have a recurring bad tag, your high rep users need to be told not to add tags like that, once or twice and I bet it stops.

Answer (score 2):

- [tips](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) most questions are looking for tips, so it's of no use for organizing or categorizing.
- [fun](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fun) two questions, one closed, both list-y. - **now removed**
- The tags I mentioned in [brand names used as tags](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221/22): [lennox](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lennox), [whirlpool](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whirlpool) (I retagged the original question with [whirpool-tub](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whirpool-tub) so that tag is used *only* as a brand name now), etc.

There are lots of low- or single-use tags that are vague and don't say anything about the question, but I'm not sure if they're blacklist worthy. Some examples: [corrugated](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corrugated), [height](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/height), [historic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historic), [inline](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inline), [solid](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solid)

Comment: I'm working through the list of tags and will add more as I find them.  Does this include tags that are ambiguous? (E.g. [tag:acoustic] is used for both acoustic ceilings and acoustics.  Also [tag:cabling].)

Comment: Yes, but ambiguous tags need to be handled differently. First we need to disambiguate - create new tags for each meaning and then retag the existing questions. Then we can blacklist.

Comment: The two questions tagged [tag:fun] have now been deleted.

Comment: I'm all in favor of disambiguation. My own pet peeve is the vent tag, since that can refer to a plumbing vent or an exhaust vent.

Answer (score 1):

I've retagged all but three of the questions (sorry for flooding the homepage). These three are closed and can be deleted if people think they can't be salvaged.

I've also updated the tag wiki to read "Please don't use this tag".

Once these last three are deleted we can request the blacklisting. It would be useful if we think others should be blacklisted to include them in the same request.