# Blacklist request - DIY

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, blacklist

Can we have "DIY" added to the tag blacklist please.

See - [Do we really need the tag "diy" on the site?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/446/do-we-really-need-the-tag-diy-on-the-site)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Done. :D [diy](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy) is now blacklisted for the site.